# Create single list from two data frames while preserving class of columns and its names

Tags: r

I have two data frames:

```
  DF1
      e   l    u
      1   0.5  1.5
      2   1    3
      3   2    4

    DF2
    e    l       u
    0.1  0.01    0.15
    0.2  0.1     0.3
    0.3  0.2     0.4
```

I want to combine these two data frames into single list like so:

```
L
[[1]]
$e: [(1 0.1);(2 0.2);(3 0.3)]     #numeric
$l: [(0.5 0.01);(1 0.1);(2 0.2)]  #numeric
$u: [(1.5 0.015);(3 0.3);(4 0.4)] #numeric
```

I have tried to rbind two data frames and then split by same column, also i was advised to use `Map` but it results in multiple lists not a single one or all variables become factors.
Thank you for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want a list of arrays.

```
> mapply(cbind, DF1, DF2, SIMPLIFY=FALSE)
$e
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1  0.1
[2,]    2  0.2
[3,]    3  0.3

$l
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]  0.5 0.01
[2,]  1.0 0.10
[3,]  2.0 0.20

$u
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]  1.5 0.15
[2,]  3.0 0.30
[3,]  4.0 0.40
```